# No module defined error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**my html page:**

```
enter code here

<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- define angular app -->
<html ng-app="daily">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- SCROLLS -->
  <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

   <!-- jQuery library -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>


  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- define angular controller -->
<body>

<div  style="background-color:black" class = "page-header">
```

Daily

```
</body>
```

**my login.html**

```
  <html>
  <body>
  <p>
   Hello
   </p>
   <body>
  <html>



enter code here
```

**my script.js:**

```
   var app=angular.module('daily',[]);
  app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
 .state('Home', {
    url: '/Home',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
  });

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Home');
```

});

Im getting Module 'daily' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument error. Not understanding the mistake i have done

Comment: could you please post your script tags,since The order of your script is very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are trying to use ui-router it is dependency to our module so include it.

```
var app = angular.module('daily', ['ui.router']);
```

**Note:** **ui-router** will not work you should use **ui.router**.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare all your dependencies in my script.js:

```
var app=angular.module('daily',[
'ui.router',
]);
  app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
 .state('Home', {
    url: '/Home',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
  });

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Home');
});
```

And in your index you didn't include the ui-router js : https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js